# Alternatives to HTTP Session state in plain-vanilla .NET web services app

Tags: c#, jquery, ajax, web-services, state

After a long struggle with the Page Lifecycle in ASP.NET and its performance, we've begun refactoring our web app to implement web services (plain-vanilla .asmx .NET web-services) and jQuery on the client-side. *NOTE: this does not implement MVC or ASP.NET in any way, these are just web services.*

In both dispensations of the application, we generate all content dynamically in a single page. In the ASP.NET dispensation, this meant (due to the Page Lifecycle) that the entire page needed to be torn down and rebuilt with (almost) every AJAX call or change to the web form. This presented a huge scalability issue for an app intended to serve many concurrent users. In the web services/jQuery dispensation, we can selectively focus on only those elements of the DOM which need to send or receive data to the server, which means far fewer requests and a much faster user experience.

The first iteration of the app showed a performance improvement by an order of magnitude; however, as we have begun to build more and more web services, the performance of the app is now at parity with the performance of the ASP.NET dispensation.

After much Googling/soul searching and load testing, it became clear that HTTP Session was the culprit. Essentially, every read (and sometimes by simply including Session in the web service method scope) is a blocking call which introduces a 500ms delay. Once you know where to look, this is well documented in the MSDN literature. As implemented, Session (if used by multiple web services by the same user) transforms asynchronous requests into synchronous requests with a 500ms buffer. We mitigate this currently by chaining all of our AJAX calls as "on success" events of each other, making them synchronous requests from the client side. This eliminates the 500ms delay incurred by requesting a read on a locked Session object.

Making the client-side app behave in a "synchronous" way has solved many of the performance issues; however, it's only a stop-gap solution for the short term.

What viable (scalable!) alternatives to Session exist, again keeping in mind that we're not on ASP.NET or MVC or WCF, etc? Our biggest hurdle is the persistence of our Metadata collection which is initialized for each user on login. This is the single most expensive operation in the app (by a factor of 10 or more), and one which we only want to execute once. Session provided a simple way to sweat to the oldies once and never look back; but this approach is looking less feasible.

One approach might be to eliminate this single Metadata collection god class and evolve this monotheistic class into a polytheistic collection of demigods. Instancing the demigods could be done more frequently at a lower cost. Feasible but requires considerable refactoring, extensive development and QA time. Another candidate is simply storing all state information in the database, but this has its own costs--latency not the least of which.

Are there any other solutions to this problem which might involve a lower level of effort to implement?

Comment: Out of curiosity, why aren't you using WCF? It can produce the exact same kind of service, with the benefit of not using legacy technology.

Comment: Just an aversion for trading the now relatively understood pros/cons of one black box Microsoft solution for the unknown pros/cons of another Microsoft solution. If you do everything the way Microsoft intends, you don't run into these problems; but when you try to make their technology think out of the box, issues arise. We've been burned a few times by this. Does WCF really solve the issue without injecting its own "idiosyncrasies"?

Comment: feel free to use obsolete technologies if you like, but they eventually stop being supported. There will never be another new feature in ASMX services, and there will be very few bug fixes, either. WCF is about 1000 times better than ASMX web services, yet can be just about as simple to use. WCF has been out for five years. Maybe time to get started or else be left far behind.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's really easy to fix your problem.

1. Turn off session in your web.config for the entire web site
2. Create a table in sql server:

   create table Session
   (
        SessionId int (or a guid)
        ...
        ...
   )
3. Create separate tables that have a foreign key back to your session table (with delete cascade) and that store session specific information
4. On the application side, either store the SessionId in a cookie or in the query string.  You can then look up all the session information you need on-demand.  This will work a lot faster than the default session state providers, since you only get information when you need the information!  Also, you don't have to carry the default session object on your back any longer.

Comment: This is the path we went down. We disabled HTTP Session completely and stored all persistent data in the database. There is a performance cost to doing this (up to 250 ms on many requests), but we no longer have any blocking calls--all requests are handled concurrently. Further optimization is needed, but this is the only complete solution to the problem.

Comment: Good to hear.  One nice thing about this approach is if you move to a different technology like Silverlight or even Java or whatever, you will be able to keep using this for persisting session information.

Answer (score 1):

Throw more hardware at it!

No, seriously. For sites like yours, you might benefit from configuring a separate machine as a session state server (see [MSDN documentation](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc732412%28v=ws.10%29.aspx)), which you can do from the IIS GUI or commandline.

After you have the state server set up, you need to set up your web config to use the new machine. A nice description of the process is available [here](http://blog.maartenballiauw.be/post/2007/11/22/ASPNET-load-balancing-and-ASPNET-state-server-%28aspnet_state%29.aspx), but in short, you set the web.config's system.web.sessionState element as follows:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<configuration>
    <system.web>
        <sessionState
            mode="StateServer"
            stateConnectionString="tcpip=your_server_ip:42424"
            cookieless="false"
            timeout="20" />
    </system.web>
</configuration>
```

Now if you want to go real heavy duty, you can have many state servers and write your own routine for resolving which server contains your session state. See a description of the process [here](http://blog.maartenballiauw.be/post/2008/01/24/ASPNET-Session-State-Partitioning-using-State-Server-Load-Balancing.aspx). This strategy should help you scale more or less indefinitely without abandoning your use of HttpSession.

Comment: Storing the sessions on a separate server will not help solve the problem of session concurrency.  ASP.NET will still lock requests that require access to the session and run them serially.

Answer (score 1):

If most of your requests only require read-access to the session then you have a simple solution.  Set the `EnableSessionState` attribute to ReadOnly and they're acquire a read-only lock on the session only.  I'm not sure how to apply this to web servcies, but I'm sure there is an equivalent setting.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa479041.aspx#aspnetsessionstate_topic3

Other than that, ASP.NET locks the session object for the entire duration of each request and effectively serializes the requests.  One solution to allow requests to run in parallel is not use the built-in sessions and roll your own solution.  The advantage here is that you can use much finer grained locking so certain aspects of the requests will have to by synchronized and will run serially, but the majority of each request can run in parallel.

An alternate solution is to simply reduce the number of parallel calls per request.  Don't try to run them in parallel at all.  Batch them up on he client side and send them as a single request.  You'll end up with less overhead in the number of requests, less likelihood of a single client hogging a lot of resources, and very likely can get better performance overall and for each aggregated request.

Comment: Reducing the number of parallel calls per request is a good idea; however, it can become difficult to manage. If the client has 10 common web service calls to make but can make any number of them, in any order, at any time, it can be difficult to assemble that into a single client-side request and more difficult to configure a web service to process that arbitrary request in a way that the client could interpret. Of course, if you could pass a functions as first class object equivalent from JavaScript to a .NET web service, that would be a horse of a different color.

Comment: @Christopher, yup, it's not an easy change.  It doesn't have to be 100% though.  Use logging or a debugging proxy like Charles or Fiddler to identify the worst offenders and just fix those.

Answer (score 0):

Without seeing your code, or what you are loading and storing in session, it's difficult to actually help you. However, a .5 second delay for session is certainly not normal in my experience. I would very much like to see the documentation that you are referring to that says this is so.

Well written asp.net (whether webforms, asmx, mvc, or other options) is certainly VERY scalable.

That being said, where is your session being stored? In process? The IIS State server? In a DB? How much data are you really storing in session? Do you really use all that data you load into session nearly every request?

It's tough to give you real answer, without understanding your problem domain better: what you have to keep state for, how large are the objects that you are using to keep state, how much traffic you have, etc etc.

Comment: ASP.NET apps with sessions, no matter how well written, are not at all scalable when you have multiple requests from a single client.  ASP.NET is scalable to server many clients, but when sessions are involved is synchronizes requests from individual clients so they run in sequence.

Comment: Session does indeed induce some scalability issues for this reason. However, and perhaps I should have been more direct, the poster might be better off at examining HOW session is being used. "a blocking call which introduces a 500ms delay" is a HELL of a lot of time. Do most browsers not limit asynch requests to 2 simultaneous calls by default? How many requests are being done simultaneously to cause this, or how much modification of state is going on, and how large is that state, especially if it's in proc!?

Comment: @Chad Ruppert, the 2 call limit was a long time ago, but is technically still in the HTTP spec.  Only IE6 I think still adheres to that limit.  8 is far more common with modern browsers (including IE8/9).

Comment: @Samuel Neff, and the mobile browsers too? :) Coding to spec is always safe. Snarkiness aside, thanks for pointing that out about the increase in default connections...  Personally, I can't remember the last time I actually used session in an app for state, and would suggest still that that is likely abuse of session in this case and could *likely* be refactored. (said without understanding what the poster is doing)

Comment: In this context, session is in proc. To clarify, the 500ms delay seems to be injected by the IIS worker process. Once session is "locked", a concurrent call will immediately wait half a second before attempting again. This does not seem to be configurable on the IIS side. This behavior is not in any documentation I have found; however, profiling the app in Fiddler shows this result every time. Clients are limited to 6 simultaneous requests. I can see each concurrent request in the block of 6 incur this 500ms delay.

Comment: @Christopher Are you writing to session with all of these calls or just reading from it? Could the statefulness you need be achieved in some other manner? Is it all that information so critical and you need security and logic on the server that you couldnt store the state for some of it clientside?