# Passing session to another sub-domain

Tags: c#, asp.net

In C# how can I pass a Session from one sub domain to another sub domain?
For instance I am using IIS localhost and I tried to send value from

`http:\\localhost\site1` to `http:\\localhost\site2`

using the below way

```
In site1

Session["test"] = "My value";

In site2

Response.Write(Convert.ToString(Session["test"]));
```

The above method worked fine to pass values from one page to another but I need values to be passed from one sub domain to another sub domain i.e. one IIS web application to another IIS web application.

Answer (score 1):

You can't do that with the default session state providers.  You will have to roll your own using the provider model (SessionStateStoreProvider) see: [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ie/ms178587.aspx)

You could also NOT use the provider model and do something like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5657561/alternatives-to-http-session-state-in-plain-vanilla-net-web-services-app/5657752#5657752)

**EDIT**
HACK: I guess you can do that. [here](http://weblogs.asp.net/lichen/archive/2011/10/05/sharing-session-state-over-multiple-asp-net-applications-with-asp-net-state-server.aspx)

Answer (score 0):

I'm doing something similar by exchanging the session ID (and the associated settings) through a common database.

I.e.

1. site 1 writes its session ID to a database table, together with all required associated settings like `test` in your above example.
2. site 1 calls an URL on site 2, passing the session ID of site 1 as a query string parameter.
3. site 2 picks up the session ID that is passed as the query string parameter.
4. site 2 uses the passed session ID as a lookup key in the database table to fetch the value of `test` ("My value" in your example)

To enhance security, I also write a timestamp to the table and let site 2 only read those rows where the session ID *and* the timestamp (with some tolerance) matches. In addition, site 2 deletes the record after reading it.

Of course this is not straight forward and possibly not 100% of what you want to achieve, it may be some idea to build upon, though.

Answer (score 0):

A session is specific to the application.  Can you post from site1 to site2 (via JQuery for example).  The post will allow you to send data (hidden).  Then assign the querystring in your post to a new session variable on site2.